# What is difference between JavaScript minify and merge?

Tags: javascript, magento-2.1.7, minified-js

I go through http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html document to optimize JS. But **bundle.js** is not generating. Only file.min.js is there.

Also third party extension not merged.

[image]

Comment: check if the third party extension javascript files are loading dynamically or after page load. If this happens, I don't think they will merge.

Answer (score 1):

Merge compiles all your Javascript files in to one big one so multiple requests aren't made for scripts you could get in one go. Minify removes any unnecessary characters in the document without changing its functionality, for example removing line breaks where unnecessary for it to work etc.

Comment: I would also add but not as part of my answer that a typical indication of whether or not merge is on is whether or not one of the names of the JS files that's been loaded looks like it's gone through SHA256 15 times