# Minified js and css not included

Tags: magento2, minified-js, minify

I perform the minification of the js and css files, I see that they were minified in the pub/static/... directory. But why in the dev-tool of the browser I see that minified files are not used?
Cache, page cache and other - was cleaned.
Magento 2.1.2, Magento 2.2.3
chrome 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)
**Current application mode: production.**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Maksim which mode are you in? Developer mode? Production mode? I believe that in developer mode, minified JS is not used, i'm gonna go find the quote hang on

Comment: yeah for both CSS and JS Minification is not applied in developer mode.

Comment: Current application mode: production.

Comment: And have you enabled javascript bundling and merging css files as well, or just minified them? Because if you've just minified them, it'll minify the code but will keep them all in separate documents

Comment: I just minified them

Comment: in that case, can you please post evidence of what the code you've written looks like VS what's inside said file highlighted in your image, it isn't gonna put it all in one file unless you also choose to bundle your javascript & merge your css

Comment: how do you know it isn't using your minified code?

Comment: I'm looking into the developer console. Files that are connected - have the full version. This can be seen by name and content

Comment: name doesn't matter with regards to minification, unless you merge all your css/bundle all your js, the names of files remain the same, it's whether or not your CSS/JS is re-written in less bytes

Comment: 'name doesn't matter with regards to minification': I`m took to the other random site - static file names was changed https://imgur.com/a/QRHAfWy

Comment: No, it doesn't, the image you just attached shows me minicart.min.js which someone has named that, it hasn't been generated, the other thing highlighted in that image is irrelevant to file name, that html attribute doesn't contribute to file name

Comment: data-requiremodule and src are two different things

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212692/what-is-difference-between-javascript-minify-and-merge?rq=1 see my answer on Javascript minification and merging, it's literally the same for CSS